# iOS navigation with TabBarController and NavigationController

Tags: ios, navigation

I have a RootViewController which is a TabBarController which have 5 ChildViewControllers. Each child is a NavigationController. Each child will be able present a FullScreenController which have `modalTransitionStyle` set to `OverFullScreen` and present by calling `showDetailViewController`. The FullScreenController need to be able to further navigate which will push another ViewController into the current NavigationController.

The problem I am facing is that the FullScreenController is presented by the TabBarController, and I cant present the original TabBarController again since it is the PresentingViewController of the FullScreenController.

Anyone know how to properly support a ViewController hierarchy with the following requirements

- Should support a navigation bar and a tab bar
- Should be able to present a FullScreenController which don't have navigation bar and tab bar
- The FullScreenController can navigate to another ViewController which have both navigation bar and tab bar
- Should support navigate backward
- Each tab on the tab bar represent its own navigation stack

Comment: I think you have conflicting requirements; either you want full screen presentation, in which case you need to exit out of this to return to the tab bar, or you want the ability to switch tabs at any time, in which case you shouldn't present full screen over the tab bar, but rather present within the current tab, which will allow the user to switch between tabs while keeping the navigation state within each tab

Comment: Ya, I know its is conflicting but this is the requirement. This behaviour is similar to Instagram's Photo Map Page which the map is FullScreen and can navigate back to outside which have the tab bar.

Comment: Right, so if you have some way of exiting the full screen then you should find yourself back at the tab bar.  You don't want to present the tab bar again, you want to unwind back to the existing instance of the tab bar, otherwise you are just moving forever into a deeper and deeper stack of view controllers.  If you are using segues then you can have a control (button etc) in your full screen views that triggers an unwind back to prior to the modal presentation

Comment: For what I know, the Instagram's Photo Map Page is not dismissed when navigate deeper. And It behaviours just like the PhotoMapController is just push into the NavigationController.

Comment: You need to think about how the user will navigate through your app.  Perhaps there is some way that you can slide the tab bar controller off/on  the screen rather than presenting over it.  Presenting a new tab bar controller isn't the way.

Comment: Looking at Instagram, it looks like they have an outer UINavigationController and when you go from the photomap to the timeline, they are just manipulating that outer navigation controller's stack by removing the tab bar controller from the root and pushing it again, or more likely they aren't using a tab bar controller, but rather their own container view controller

Comment: I think its more then that. The navigation history of each tab is independent, so basically you can have each tab having a photomap in its own navigation history. Wrapping an outer UINavigationController seem not enough to provide such navigation history.

Comment: I guess they are not having a TabBarController, each ViewController have its own NavigationViewController's toolbar. And a custom subclass of the NavigationViewController to mimic the independent TabBar behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming there was still a navigation controller per tab, but also an out navigation controller to handle the switch between the full screen and tab bar views

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution still not enough for my requirement since my FullScreenViewController need to see through the ViewController under it. And as far as I know I can't push a ViewController Over another in a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You can add full screen view as child controller to Each Tab bar controller and keep the close button from full screen view (close will take them back to tab bar view).

Hope this will help.